# Getting Undefined index: REQUEST_URI - When Run Artisan Commands in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I keep getting the error below every time I try to run an artisan command on Laravel, I'm on the project directory.

For example, I run this command:

```
php artisan make:migration create_stats_table
```

And I get this error:

```
  [ErrorException]              
  Undefined index: REQUEST_URI
```

No matter what command I run, I get the same error, even `php artisan --version` returns this error. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code expects to have this index, but you're running PHP in CLI mode.
`REQUEST_URI` variable of `$_SERVER` superglobal is only available if you're reaching script by browser.

Comment: Yes, I found the problem, I had created a new route with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and others variables in it, I guess I'll have to find another way to pass variables with `@include`in views.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned already this variable doesn't exist if you run by the CLI.  If you can't get around the issue and avoid using it a work around is to use isset()

```
if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){ 
...
}
```